# I use drupal 6 i need to get full URL

Tags: url, drupal

I am using drupal 6.
my URL is http://myurl.net/fr/node/433/post.
I need to get http://myurl.net/fr through code. 
through global $base_url i am not able to get.
Please can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `$_SERVER` variable, it not depends on Drupal.

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
```